# How to prevent marker from repeating in clustermanager

Tags: android, arraylist, collections, markerclusterer, geofire

I'm using geofire library to load data from firebase3 in a specifique region, but when i add new marker to database and i check my map i found out that multiple marker has been added in the same latlng coordinates, my question is how to prevent marker from been repeating in the same coordinates.
Here is the Geofire methode :

```
geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {


                    try{
                        items.add(new MyItem(location.latitude, location.longitude));
                        Log.d("onKey","called");
                    }catch (ClassCastException e){
                        Log.d("classCastException","");
                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyExited(String key) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryReady() {
                    parseJsonToList();
                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
```

ParseJsonToList methode :

```
private void parseJsonToList() {


        itemss = clusterManagerAlgorithm.getItems();
        try {


            items.removeAll(itemss);
        }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            Log.d("itemsDoesn't exist"," : ");
        }


        mClusterManager.clearItems();
        mClusterManager.cluster();
        mClusterManager.addItems(items);
        Log.d("items"," : " + items);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code what you have published, two points can be a source of the issue.

First, it is multiple calling of `GeoQueryEventListener.onKeyEntered()`, to fix it you can make a workaround like this:

```
try{
    MyItem myItem = new MyItem(location.latitude, location.longitude);
    if (!items.contains(myItem)) {
        items.add(myItem);
    }
    Log.d("onKey","called");
    }catch (ClassCastException e){
         Log.d("classCastException","");
    }
```

Second, maybe you forgot to override `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods of the `MyItem` class. So when you are calling `items.removeAll(itemss);` no one item has deleted.

In both cases an overriding `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods of the `MyItem` class required. It is easy to do with [the autogenerating function](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-equals-and-hashcode-wizard.html) in AndroidStudio.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yeah that solved the problem, but it create a simple problem of performance is that all the items removed from the map and only after 3s items reloded again. thing that i don't have in my previous code Please is there any solution ?